# scrapy pass argu to selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

In the website, have javascript need to select a date and click to get the result.
how can I pass args to selenium and select?

I have already have middleware

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        body = self.driver.page_source

        return HtmlResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8',request = request)
```

Comment: You're already passing args to this function, so just pass another arg identifying the element to click on.

Comment: But the method is called by scrapy internal itself, how can I call dowloader middleware function directly from scrapy ?

Comment: Your middleware just return the page source of opened page of `request.url`, not a real browser.  You can simply think the return value is a long String, so you can't click on any element on the web page as a browser.  You can use `Selenium` to simulate a user operating on browser to open a page, click etc.

Comment: @JohnGordon, i found out I can call the spider class var directly, problem solved